# using sed to replace complex string (remove "_")

Tags: unix, replace, sed

I would like to replace some complex strings

```
ChrLGE22C19W28_E50C23 to ChrLGE22C19W28
Chr1_random to Chr1random
```

How can I do it using sed?

I used:

```
sed 's@/ChrLGE22C19W28_E50C23@ChrLGE22C19W28'
```

and did not work...

thanks
Clarissa

Comment: what's the logic used?

Comment: your requirement is not well specified. you want `ChrLGE22C19W28_E50C23` to `ChrLGE22C19W28E50C23` or `ChrLGE22C19W28`?

Comment: All you want to do is remove '_'? If so, try `tr -d _ < input.txt > output.txt`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either

```
sed 's/ChrLGE22C19W28_E50C23/ChrLGE22C19W28/'
```

or

```
sed 's@ChrLGE22C19W28_E50C23@ChrLGE22C19W28@'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!
The command sed 's/ChrLGE22C19W28_E50C23/ChrLGE22C19W28/' worked well

Clarissa